# makefile utility is not throwing error

Tags: c

Hello i am trying to compiler my code using make utility but i am getting error as

```
print.c:1:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
make: *** [print.o] Error 1
```

please help me to fix today is first time i am using make utility

```
outfile: main.o print.o header.o
    cc main.o print.o header.o -o outfile
main.o: main.c
    cc -c main.c -o main.o
print.o: print.c
    cc -c print.c -o print.o
header.o: header.c
    cc -c print.c -o print.o
```

Comment: Problem exists in the C program(`print.c`) itself.

Comment: Read the manual. For example, [the GNU Manual discusses error messages and what they mean.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html)

Comment: Your line to build `header.o` is fairly broken.

Comment: Also, make sure you're indenting with tabs and not spaces; make get's angry if you don't.

Comment: `header.o: header.c cc -c print.c -o print.o ` --> `header.o: header.c cc -c header.c -o header.o`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the error is not necessarily in your Makefile, but because of a failed compilation. In the documentation for [error messages](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html), it says:

> Errors that are fatal are prefixed with the string ***.
>
> Error messages are all either prefixed with the name of the program
>   (usually `make`), or, if the error is found in a makefile, the name of
>   the file and line number containing the problem.
>
> `[foo] Error NN`
>
> `[foo] signal description`
>
> These errors are not really make errors at all. They mean that a
>   program that make invoked as part of a recipe returned a non-0 error
>   code (`Error NN`), which make interprets as failure, or it exited in
>   some other abnormal fashion (with a signal of some type).

For example, on my machine, GCC returns an error status of 127 for failed compilation.